# How to use the results of "file" (Name of Creating Application: Microsoft Word) to search for a specific string?

Tags: files, find, search, string

I am trying use the results of "file" which returns info about the file/s I specify.

E.g.

```
file *.doc 'all .doc extensions
```

This then returns information about the file including "Name of Creating Application: Microsoft Word" Now, I am trying to search the results for the string "Word". I'm stuck here. How do I actually do that?

*This is what I tried after hours of searching. I just don't know what word I'm looking for. Please advise.

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -lh "Microsoft Word" | xargs -I % mv % ../NewDirectory/
```

I think this searches for the string "Word" inside the files itself and moves it to the new directory.

Comment: so then are you saying you're trying to run the `file` command on any files that have a .doc extension?

Comment: @Dave Yes, I am trying to run the "file" command on .doc extensions only and then move the files that will return "Microsoft Word" string. I do this because some files have wrong extensions (xls, ppt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to move files from the current directory and its subdirectories recursively to another directory, but only if the `file` command reports them as “Microsoft Word” files. That is, you're interested in the files for which `file "$filename" | grep 'Microsoft Word'` produces some output.

An easy way is to take things calmly and to it file by file. If you only want the files in the current directory, you can use a `for` loop and a wildcard pattern:

```
for f in *.doc; do
  if …
done
```

What's the condition? We want to test if `Microsoft Word` appears in the output of `file "$f"`. I use `file --` to protect against files whose name begins with `-`.

```
for f in *.doc; do
  if file -- "$f" | grep -s 'Microsoft Word'; then
    …
  fi
done
```

All we need to do is add the command to move the files.

```
for f in *.doc; do
  if file -- "$f" | grep -s 'Microsoft Word'; then
    mv -- "$f" ../NewDirectory/
  fi
done
```

If you want to look for files in subdirectories as well, use the [`**` wilcdard pattern](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) for recursive globbing. In bash, it needs to be activated with `shopt -s globstar` (in ksh93, you need `set -o globstar`, and in zsh it works out of the box; other shells lack this feature). Beware that bash ≤4.2 follows symbolic links to directories.

```
for f in **/*.doc; do
  if file -- "$f" | grep -s 'Microsoft Word'; then
    mv -- "$f" ../NewDirectory/
  fi
done
```

Note that all moved files end in `../NewDirectory/`, no subdirectories are created. If you want to reproduce the directory tree, you can use [string manipulation constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to extract the directory part of the file name and `mkdir -p` to create the target directory if necessary.

```
for f in ./**/*.doc; do
  if file "$f" | grep -s 'Microsoft Word'; then
    d="${f%/*}"
    mkdir -p ../NewDirectory/"$d"
    mv "$f" ../NewDirectory/"$d"
  fi
done
```

Rather than parse the output of `file`, which is somewhat fragile, you might prefer to parse `file -i`, which prints standardized strings.

Comment: Thanks for explaining in detail! You just saved my ass. Also, about the subdirectories I didn't need it but it wouldn't hurt to learn! :) 

Great Community! I hope I can help next time.

Comment: @A.Mist if this answer your question you should except it as the answer

Answer (score 2):

Your first `file` example will not work because of the unmatched single quote, but I think you already found that because of your second example.

If you do:

```
find . -type f
```

you can look at the output. Those are filenames. If you want to select something from that output use `grep` directly

```
find . -type f  |  grep "Microsoft Word"
```

that searches through the filenames, not through the contents of the files listed. That is not completely accurate, as a filename could have a newline in them, making the output incomplete if a filename with "Microsoft Word" in it has a newline as part of the name.

If you do:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -lh "Microsoft Word"
```

the `xargs` part actually hands the filenames to grep (the `-print0` for `find` and `-0` for `xargs` is to handle filename with newlines).
This searches for the whole string "Microsoft Word" not just "Word" **in the files**.

The `-lh` specified for `grep` lists the filenames, and there might be a problem with that as newlines in filenames are printed normally, you should continue to use NUL terminated filenames by specifying -Z as well. If you don't specify `-l` you get the contents of the lines matches as well, which would make further processing (your `mv`) impossible.

If you want to move all the files into one directory it is often easier to use  `mv -t` instead of mucking with `xargs`' `-I` option (which allows you to put parameters `xargs` reads from its input at a different place than the default end-of-line but which is slower as mv is called once for each file):

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -lhZ "Microsoft Word" | xargs -0 mv -t ../NewDirectory/
```

And this moves all files somewhere under the current directory, with "Microsoft Word" in part of their **content** to the `NewDirectory` that is next to the current directory. Please note that `../NewDirectory` has to exist.

Comment: Thank you. Does this use the results of "file" command or will it produce a similar output? I am curious.

Comment: @A.Mist I am not 100% sure what you mean by "this". If you are referring to the `grep -Z` part, then yes: it produces a list of NUL terminated filenames, just like `file -print0` does. The complete sequence produces nothing as output, it just moves the files. If you are new at this, it often helps to make a few files with known simple content ('aa', 'ab', or 'bb') in small directory hierarchy, **under a new directory** and try the commands out. Make it simple enough so that you know what should happen if you run such a sequence and can check the results.